# how to do Form validation in JSP using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsp

How can we validate a login page or a registration page using Jsp??

Can we do this in Eclipse??

only sereve side validation is required

Comment: how to do form validation in jsp. using javascript. when only server-side validation is required. there is so much wrong with this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the validation done server-side, yet done in javascript, you use Ajax to send a request to the server-side to validate.